# Error: could not detect network (event="noNetwork", code=NETWORK_ERROR, version=providers/5.7.2), why can't I deploy to mainnet

Tags: remix, ethers.js, hardhat-deploy

```
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers");
require ("dotenv").config();

/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.10",
  networks:{
    mainnet: {
      url: `https://eth-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/APIKEY`,
      accounts: [process.env.PRIVATE_KEY],
    }
  }
};
```

i want to know what is really wrong cos infura rpc url also return this error

Comment: How are you running the deployment script?

Comment: Are you using the url as `https://eth-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/APIKEY` only or are you renaming `APIKEY`?

Answer (score 0):

Please verify that you have this in your `package.json`:

```json
{
  ...,
  "scripts": {
    ...,
    "deploy": "npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network mainnet"
  }
}
```

Or use directly the command `npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network mainnet`.

For more info, see: https://hardhat.org/tutorial/deploying-to-a-live-network

Comment: npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network mainnet.

Comment: I renamed the API key to my infura API, but it kept on returning this same error

Comment: And it is returning this error, that I posted, {
  ...,
  "scripts": {
    ...,
    "deploy": "npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network mainnet"
  }
} It is not in my package.json

Comment: Do you store your APIKEY in your .env ?

Comment: No I didn't just my private

Comment: Did you test to deploy it on local network through `npx hardhat test` for example ?

Comment: No, I just test on remix and then deploy with hardhat

Comment: You can alternatively deploy on mainnet from [Remix](https://remix-ide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/create_deploy.html#deploy-the-contract)

Comment: The functionalities I later built into the contract will only allow me to use hardhat,